# I want to remove element from an array

Tags: arrays, indexing, element

How can i do that. my array is [1,2,3,4,5] after i tried to remove the index of 0, the result looks like [2,2,3,4,0]

```
 public static void remove (int[] array, int index) {
    for (int i = index; i < array.length - 1; i++)
    {
        array[index] = array[index+1];
    }
    array[array.length-1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?
Please tag the language.

Comment: What do you mean with "remove"? What does the expected resulting array look like?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the line in your loop to

```
array[i] = array[i+1];
```

Comment: @MustafaFurkanAyaz Glad that I could help. In case you are content the answer is correct you could accept the answer or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use there **ArrayUtils** class to remove an element from array more easily than by doing it yourself.

One thing to remember is that Arrays are fixed size in Java, once you create an array you can not change their size, which means removing or deleting an item doesn't reduce the size of the array.

You can delete using -

> arrayName = ArrayUtils.remove(arrayName, index_to_remove)

What you need to do is create a new array and copy the remaining content of this array into a new array using **System.arrayCopy()** or any other means.

For Object arrays, You can also convert Array to List and then remove a particular object and convert List back to the array